# First unity game: How do I call my RestartGame function from a second Scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes, a game scene and a game-over scene.

In the gamescene, there lives a GameState game object with a script hat controls health, etc. and it also has a RestartGame() function.

In the second scene there are only some UI elements such as the restart game button (legacy ui). Now I know I have to drag the GameState game-object into the onClick-Event thingy on the button. But I can't because those two things live in differen scenes.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does the RestartGame() function do anything?  It doesn't make sense that the button is in a different scene than the functionality of that button.  Can you move your functionality to the scene with the button?

Comment: You could use `FindObjectOfType` in the second scene in order to find the object

Answer (score 0):

To restart your game you should just reload the scene, but make sure to initialize everything at the start of the game scene, but this really depends from your game architecture.

( using SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() )